# Factorization of sum of terms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found in a solution that expands the following series,

$$ 
=\sum_{i=1}^m{\left( \alpha _{ik+1}p_{k+1}+\alpha _{ik+2}p_{k+2}+...+\alpha _{in}p_n \right) ^T\left( \alpha _{ik+1}p_{k+1}+\alpha _{ik+2}p_{k+2}+...+\alpha _{in}p_n \right)} 
$$

To collect alike terms and unalike terms,
$$ 
=\sum_{i=1}^m{\sum_{j=k+1}^n{\left( \alpha _{ij}p_{j}^{T}p_j\alpha _{ij} \right)}+}\sum_{i=1}^m{\sum_{j=k+1}^n{\sum_{L=k+1,L\ne k}^n{\left( \alpha _{ij}p_jp_L\alpha _{iL} \right)}}} 
$$

**Question**: I think there is something wrong with this sum in the equation above as it should have $L\ne j$ not $L\ne k$,

$$
\sum_{L=k+1,L\ne j}^n{\left( \alpha _{ij}p_j p_L \alpha _{iL} \right)}
$$